# How to hide overflow of specific object if total width exceeds window (CSS only?)

Tags: html, css

When styling a navigation bar for use on mobile and desktop devices, I have been trying to hide the overflow of one of the items (the page's title) if the total width of all items in the navigation bar exceeds the width of the window. For example, if the total width of the navigation bar is 400px, and the viewport width is 350px, then all items apart from the title keep their set width, and the overflow of the title is hidden. The item in question is in the middle of the list, like so:

```
<html>
  <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li id="linkHome"><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
            <li id="pageName"><span>Title</span></li>
            <li id="logOut"><a href="/logout">LOGOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</html>
```

And the current CSS I am using to style is this:

```
.navbar ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar li {
    float: left;
}

.navbar li a {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li span {
    max-width: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;;
}
```

Another thing, I would much prefer not to use JavaScript, so if there is a CSS only solution that would be much preferred!

Comment: use media query

Comment: @lakhvirkumar Works great, thanks!

Comment: upvote for me please below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css @media, here is an example

```
@media (max-width:767px){
  .class-name {
     width: 50% !important;
  }
}
```

max-width is the max screen width this css will applied on, you can change max-width by min-width and adjust its value as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use media query:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 500px) { 
//css goes here
}
```